# Getting error while transfering PGP file through FTP : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive

Tags: file, ftp, transfer, pgp

I am trying to upload a PGP encrypted file through FTP. But I am getting an error message as follows:

**The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.**

I am using the following code and getting the error at line:

**Stream ftpStream = response.GetResponse();**

Is there any one who can help me out ASAP.

Following is the code sample:

```
FtpWebRequest request =
  WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.website.com/sample.txt.pgp") as FtpWebRequest; 
request.UsePassive = true;    
FtpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as FtpWebResponse;    
Stream ftpStream = response.GetResponse();    
int bufferSize = 8192;    
byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];    
using (FileStream fileStream =
       new FileStream("localfile.zip", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    int nBytes;
    while((nBytes = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize) > 0)
    {
        fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, nBytes);
    }
}
```

Regards,
Sumeet

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to upload using `GetResponse()`?
You need at least `request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;` and `request.GetRequestStream();`

Answer (score 0):

```
ftp.UsePassive = true;
ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
ftp.KeepAlive = false;
ftp.UseBinary = true;
ftp.UsePassive = true;
ftp.Timeout = int.MaxValue;
ftp.ReadWriteTimeout = int.MaxValue;
ftp.Proxy = null;
ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(values.UserName, values.Password);
```